# How does \everyhbox work?

Tags: tex-core, badness

Knuth in the TexBook Chapter 24, gives a short list of the `every` commands. The `\everyhbox` command inserts a token list - as its name implies- before a horizontal box.

Here is a short example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\begin{document}
 \begingroup
     \everyhbox{a} % change this to $a$ to see the issue!
     \def\oneLineBox#1#2%
     {%
          \hfuzz=0pt
          \overfullrule=0.25pt
          \setbox0=\hbox spread#2{#1}%
          \setbox1=\hbox{\the\badness}% 
          \setbox2=\hbox to 5cm{\box0\hfil\box1}%
          \box2
     }
     \oneLineBox{Badness of line }{-1em}
     \oneLineBox{Badness of line }{-0.50em}
     \oneLineBox{Badness of line }{-0.39em}
     \oneLineBox{Badness of line }{0em}
     \oneLineBox{Badness of line }{1em}
     \oneLineBox{Badness of line }{2em}
     \oneLineBox{Badness of line }{3em}
 \endgroup

\end{document}
```

The `oneLineBox` macro above set ups some boxes and using `\everybox` we add the letter `a` in each horizontal box. But when we change the letter to a math letter say `$a$`, the badness is shown as zero, why? Surely the badness of the line did not disappear? Similar results can be obtained by changing `\badness` to `\hbadness`, this time TeX displays 1000 for all the lines. The `overfullrule` also seems to go a bit awry!

Comment: @TH Sorry, I edited the code and wrote `\badness`. I was playing with the code and copied wrongly. Will you please give it another go?

Comment: I moved my comment into my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with `\everyhbox`. The real issue is that constructing a math list involves constructing hboxes and the `\badness` reflects that.

For example,

```
\setbox0\hbox spread -1em{X}
\the\badness

\setbox0\hbox spread -1em{X}
$a$\the\badness
\bye
```

The first box is infinitely bad because the glue shrunk beyond its limit. In the second case, the box is again infinitely bad, but the `\badness` reflects that of the `a` and its italic correction, I believe.

Okay, I finally tracked down where this happens in tex.web. `mlist_to_hlist` converts a math list to a horizontal list as per the rules in Appendix G. In particular, it calls `hpack` which contains

```
last_badness := badness(...)
```

and this global variable is exactly the badness reported by `\badness`.

I'm not sure if this is ever actually mentioned in *The TeXbook*—I looked through texbook.tex (my copy of the book is in my office) and didn't see any mention of it. It doesn't appear to be in *TeX by Topic* either.

`\hbadness` and `\vbadness` are parameters that control the "amount of tolerance before TeX reports and underfull or overfull horizontal/vertical box" (TeX by Topic). That it doesn't change is not surprising.

Comment: I was just about to post more-or-less the same thing :-) The easiest way to see what is going on is to use `\everyhbox{\showthe\badness$a$\showthe\badness}`.

Comment: @TH You are right it has nothing to do with `everyhbox`. I changed the code to that suggested by Joseph and removed `the\badness` in box1 and it displays two sets of badness. One for the `$a$` and one for the text line, both correct now. Thanks!

Comment: I was looking through tex.web and the woven version to find exactly where this gets set and ran across this great line: "The simplest math formula is, of course '$ $', when no noads are generated. The next simplest cases involve a single character, e.g., '$x$'. Even though such cases may not seem to be very interesting, the reader can perhaps understand how happy the author was when '$x$' was first properly typeset by TeX." Yes, yes I can.

Comment: @TH it is a great comment by Knuth! Is it still possible to get the original pascal compiler and code and run it on a windows machine?

Comment: @Yiannis: I'm not sure. I don't know anything about Windows. That said, looking through texbook.tex, I saw this comment, "Also, TeX was first implemented on a DEC-10. The \catcode for <space> is 10. My birthday is January 10. Can this all be just a coincidence?" I guess he means a PDP-10. So maybe you should track one of those down. =)

Comment: @TH I can't afford the larger apartment to house a PDP-10:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Regarding "Is it still possible to get the original pascal compiler and code and run it" -- see http://ctan.org/pkg/tex-fpc and https://github.com/kisonecat/web2js (both work).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Wow thanks. This is great